# Inline server code in client page

Tags: asp.net

Not a difficult question but i can't seem to find a decent answer to it:

inline server code in client page, 
what are the usage/different of these:

```
<% %>
<%# %>
<%= %>
```

are there any more?

Answer (score 1):

```
<%    %>
```

Is used for executing arbitrary blocks of code on the server. Usually some type of control statement is place inside of them.

```
<%= %>
```

Writes content out to the response stream, similar to Response.Write().

Making something like (below) possible.

```
<table>
<%
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        %><tr><td><%= i %></td></tr><%
%>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<% %>` tag is used for code blocks. The tag doesn't output anything in itself. Example:

```
<% int answer = 42; %>
```

The `<%# %>` tag is used for data binding.

The `<%= %>` tag is used for value output. The tag evaluates the expression and the result is written to the page. Example:

```
<%= answer %>
```

There is also the `<%: %>` tag, which is the same as the `<%= %>` tag except that the output is HTML encoded.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

<%$ %> is used for Resources.